# Solution of a linear system of difference equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

In the discrete case of dynamical systems, we are interested with how points in space behave under iterations by a particular map, $f$. If we restrict ourselves to the plane, and only consider the case when $f$ is linear, we can represent the mapping by multiplication with a coefficient matrix $A$. Since maps are iterative, we have, in general, that $$p_{n+1} = A^{n + 1} p_0 = Ap_n$$ where $p_i$ is any point in the plane after $i$ iterations. In general, how do we reach the general solution of such a system given by $X_{n+1} = AX_n$, for $A \in \mathbb{M}_{2\times2}$ and $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for any $i$? I've had trouble finding concrete answers online, and the YouTube videos I've found have offered little solace. For the sake of clarity, let $\displaystyle A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I am afraid that you will not find a short way to describe a general solution anywhere. The form of the solution depends, in the first instance, on whether $A$ has real, or a pair of complex, eigenvalues. Then, one takes into account the position moduli of the eigenvalues wrt one. Sometimes, when you are interested in the stability of the fixed point, that is sufficient.  For an algorithm to compute $A^n$, see, e.g., [An Introduction to Difference Equations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245346142_An_Introduction_to_Difference_Equation) by S. Elaydi, pp. 118-125.

Comment: Jordan canonical form. Nothing less and nothing more.

Comment: I edited your equation "$p_{n + 1} = A^n p_0 = Ap_n$" to read "$p_{n + 1} = A^{n + 1} p_0 = Ap_n$" since that must be the case according to your definiton(s).  Feel free to change it back if I erred.  Cheers!